# error C2440 and functors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

maybe you would know, I get an error:

```
 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' 
              Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast
```

It goes to ' file in MS VS 2010 folder:

```
template<class _Other1,
        class _Other2>
        _Pair_base(_Other1&& _Val1, _Other2&& _Val2)
        : first(_STD forward<_Other1>(_Val1)),
            second(_STD forward<_Other2>(_Val2))
        {   // construct from moved values
        }
```

I was looking for different solutions but could not find a correct one.

Comment: What is the type of `functors`?

Comment: `pair<EnterFunctor*, ExitFunctor*>(NULL,sessionStartExit)` doesn't need `<,>` type part.

Comment: @billz: It does need the `<,>` part. Recall that `pair` is a template class (no type deduction) not a template function like `make_pair` (which can deduce types from arguments).

Comment: Was [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) part of your solution search?

Comment: Pankow, we reject your edits because they should be added as a comment (or possibly as a separate answer, giving more detail to why you can not do it that way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says

```
'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'EnterFunctor *'
```

The only part of your code you share is

```
functors.push_back(make_pair(sessionStartFunc, 
    pair<EnterFunctor*, ExitFunctor*>(NULL,sessionStartExit)));
```

If `NULL` is #defined as 0 this gives you an `int` but you promised a `pair` of pointers, so as the next line of the error says you can use a cast to make `NULL` the right type of pointer.